# Working with convolution-like sums

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, convolution

Let $a_k =0 \  \forall k \le 0$ be an integer sequence, and define

$$f(n,s):=\sum_{k=0}^n k^s a_k a_{n-k}$$

We can clearly express $f(n,1)$ in terms of $f(n,0)$ as:
$$f(n,1)=\frac{n}{2} f(n,0)$$

My question is whether there is a way to express $f(n,2)$ in terms of $f(n,1)$ and, if there is not any, how to disprove it.

More generally, when I was working with this type of discrete convolutions, I noticed that it is possible to express $f(n,2l+1)$ in terms of combinations of $f(n,2l), \dots ,f(n,0)$ just by making equal:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^s a_k a_{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n (n-k)^s a_k a_{n-k}$$

And developing Newton's Binomial. An alternative proof can be found by taking its Fourier transform and working with its properties.

However, this method does not work for even values of $s$, hence my question of wether there exists an alternative method for finding such an expression (while my question if focused on the case $f(n,2)$, there may exist a generalization for $n=2l$). If it were not possible, it would be great to have a proof of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With $f(z)=\sum_k a_kz^k$ then $\sum_k a_{n-k} a_k k$ are the coefficients of $f(z) zf'(z)$ and $n \sum_k a_{n-k} a_k$ are those of $z(f(z)^2)' = 2z f'(z)f(z)$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your answer. I would be more interested in even values of $n$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a formula of the form $f(n,2) = g\big( n, f(n,1) \big)$ for some function $g$ (which, in particular, does not take the invididual $a_j$ into account).

Such a function cannot exist, as we can see just by taking $n=2$:
\begin{align*}
f(2,2) &= a_1^2 + 4a_0a_2 \\
f(2,1) &= a_1^2 + 2a_0a_2.
\end{align*}
There are certainly triples $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$ for which $a_1^2 + 2a_0a_2$ gives the same value but for which $a_1^2 + 4a_0a_2$ does not; for example, $(a_0,a_1,a_2)=(1,1,5)$ and $(a_0,a_1,a_2)=(3,1,1)$ have this property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I would be interested in a general case rather than in the specific counterexample for $n=2$. And, following your statement, you should take into account both that $a_0=0$ and the case $f(2,0)$, isn't it?